# Ionic 3 get contents of an asset file

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm building an app to show the contents of a book. I have 3 pages in this app:

Page 1. List of buttons that links to chapters; (`ChaptersPage`)
 Page 2. List of buttons that links to pages of a chapter; (`PagesPage`)
 Page 3. Page content; (`PageContentPage`)

Pages 1 and 2 are inside a Tab, so when the user selects a chapter he goes to the next tab, then select a page of the chapter and then get the page content. The tabs will look like this:
[image]

All pages and chapters are on his own folders. My app folders looks like this:

```
src
|_ app
|_ assets
   |_ icon
   |_ images
   |_ chapters
      |_ 1
         |_page_1.txt
         |_page_2.txt
      |_ 2
         |_page_1.txt
         |_page_2.txt
      |_ 3
         |_page_1.txt
         |_page_2.txt
      |_  ...
|_ pages
|_ services
|_ ...
```

First, when the user selects a chapter I need to look how many pages are inside the chapter folder, so I can list the correct number of buttons. I'm trying to use [ionic native File plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/) but I have no success. Using the example on the file plugin doc I'm always getting "Directory doesnt exist":

```
this.file.checkDir(this.file.applicationDirectory, 'assets/chapters/2').then(_ => 
   console.log('Directory exists')
).catch(err => console.log('Directory doesnt exist'));
```

So, my question is: how can I read how many files are inside a chapter folder? and after, how can I get the contents of a page.txt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
readPage() {
    this.http.request('../assets/chapters/1/page_1.txt')
          .map(res => res.text())
          .subscribe(text => {
            this.txtContent= text;
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.err("Path not found with error:", error);
          });
}
```

Comment: `.map(res => res.text()    })` looks wrong it has an extra `}`

Comment: Fixed. Nice catch @Whitecat .

Answer (score 0):

First of change this code block , this will get you to the directory you want

```
this.file.checkDir(this.file.applicationDirectory, './chapters/2').then(_ => 
   console.log('Directory exists')
).catch(err => console.log('Directory doesnt exist'));
```

Comment: doesn't work that way in current ionic version?
I have a folder named "img" placed in assets and it can´t be detected by using this.file.checkFile

Answer (score 0):

- try below for android device:

```
this.file.checkDir(this.file.applicationDirectory,'public/assets/chapters/2')
.then(_ => 
   console.log('Directory exists')
).catch(err => console.log('Directory doesnt exist'));
```